# mlbench example

Tags: r, sample

I heard R is the "de facto" language amongst statistical software developers, and I'm giving it a try. I already know the basics, but it still looks "weird" to me (a C developer). I think it would be very useful to see a working example to see how a real R program is built.
I thought that an R solution for any of the mlbench problems would be optimal, because I'm already familiar with it and it would allow me to compare it to other languages, but any other "toy problem" example is welcome.

The `mlbench` package is pointed out in the answers below, but it seems that it provides only sample data and functions to generate sample data, with the exception of a generic bayes classifier. I'm searching for solutions of any of the mlbench data problems (DNA, Glass, Ionosphere, etc.). Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [mlbench](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlbench/index.html) package is what you are looking for? You can inspect the implementation by using print(nameOfFunction).

Comment: You can actually just type the function name without parentheses and it will return itself (i.e. no need to `print`).